Heatmap with population and travel time using ArcGIS Pro
I have two different layers one which consists of polygons that represent travel time (15, 30, 45) and another which contains demographic information. I want to create a heat map similar to this that shows the areas and population that fall within each travel time from a transit center and outside the total travel area.
The map I want to create is similar to this:

I did the summarize within to add the population information to the travel time layer, however that only allows me to show population within the polygons and still I don't know how to visualize it.
Here is what I have:


Are you asking how to visualise population beyond your 15-45 min travel time polygons? In the UK map you show it appears anything beyond 60 minutes is just red.

Yes, essentially I want the population layer to show how it falls within each time polygon, with the population outside of the polygons showing in red. I don't know if that makes sense.

Well you have transferred population to your travel time polygons, sounds like you want to create a "blank" background. Why not use minimum bounding geometry tool to create a rectangle from the extent of data, colour it red and display it below your travel time polygons?
